# How to wipe /data on nexus 4 to install ubuntu-touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm trying to replace my current Ubuntu Touch Developer Preview with the next daily build.

I'm following the directions here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

After entering 'phablet-flash -l' I get the following error. Not enough space in /data, found 3.9G. The directions say to "try wiping the /data partition on your device and redeploy". How do you do that?

When I plug in the device it always says "Unable to mount Nexus 4 Unable to open MTP device '[usb:002,010]'". Do I need to use adb or ssh to wipe /data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several methods at your disposal to wipe your `/data` partition:

**Through Android**

- Boot into Android normally.
- Go into `Settings` **>** `Backup & reset` **>** `Factory data reset`
- This will perform a `Factory Reset` which basically wipes `/data` and `cache` partitions, but keeps `/system` in tact.

**Through Fastboot**

- Boot your device into *bootloader* mode: power-down your device, and reboot into the *bootloader* by holding the *power button* and the *volume down button* together for several seconds.
- You can also reboot into *bootloader* mode via *adb* by executing the
  following command (while your device is booted into *Android*, with *USB Debugging* turned on):

  `adb reboot-bootloader`
- Once you're in the *bootloader*, run the following *fastboot* command:

  `fastboot erase data`

**Through Recovery**

- Boot your device into *bootloader* mode (follow instructions above).
- Once you're in the *bootloader*, use the *volume buttons* to select *Recovery*, and press the *power button* to reboot into *recovery*.
- You can also reboot into *recovery* mode via *adb* by executing the
  following command (while your device is booted into *Android*, with *USB Debugging* turned on):

  `adb reboot recovery`
- If you have the stock `<3e> recovery` or `ClockworkMod`, select `wipe data/factory reset` option. Use the `volume buttons` to navigate to it, and the `power button` to select it and start the wipe.
- If you have `TWRP`, tap on *Wipe*, and select *Factory Reset*.

Good luck!

Comment: Or you can also simply run `phablet-flash -b` to bootstrap the device, wiping out all user data.